# Change format of Date Range Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am facing a problem that I want to change date format of **Date Range Picker**, I tried to fix all the formats and it works but the only problem left behind is when you open date range window and close it without clicking **Apply** or **Cancel** button it automatically changes the date with `/` separated format, is there any way to set this in same format like **YYYY-MM-DD**

Here is my Js Code

```
$(function() {
    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();
    function cb(start, end) {
        $('input[name="datefilter"]').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' TO ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    }

    $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' TO ' + picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
    $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' TO ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
```

Comment: Have you tryed adding -> dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd '  ?

Comment: yes i tried all the ways

Comment: Check out this http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate , might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' // --------Here
    },
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
}, cb);
```

Comment: worked thanks but i want to place TO between two dates e.g. **2017-03-01 TO 2017-03-10** instead of **2017-03-01 - 2017-03-10**

Comment: I fixed it by adding **separator: ' TO '**

Answer (score 0):

```
var mystring = "2017/03/10";
var res = mystring.replace(/\\//g , "-");
```

Output :

> 2017-03-10

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({   
    locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
    }
    ...
```